# Using nested for loops in PHP seems to skip over needed values, how to use array_maps() to get rid of duplicate items in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, r, loops

I'm translating some code from R to PHP that find the distance between two given points in an array, and compares them to a user given cap.

If the distance is less than or equal to the cap, the points in the two respective groups should be placed in separate arrays called 
`$aResults` and `$bResults`. I'm comparing the output from my PHP script using nested for loops vs a slower, but more thorough algorithm I wrote in R just to make sure I was getting every point. I also created two counter variables to keep track of which spot in the matches arrays the values should be placed, called `$aCounter` and `$bCounter`.

```
for ($i= 0; $i < count($groupA); $i++)
{
    $bCounter = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($groupB); $j++)
    {
        if (distance($groupA[$i], $groupB[$j]) <= $cap)
        {
             $aMatches[$aCounter] = $i + 1;
             $bMatches[$bCounter] = $j + 1;
        }
        $bCounter++;
    }
    $aCounter++;
}
```

`$bResults` matches the `bOutput` vector in R perfectly, but the `$aResults` seems to be off for one or two points in each interval of matches:

For example:

- R will output: 13, 14, 15....
- PHP will output: 14....

I did call `array_maps()` on `$aMatches` to get rid of duplicates (super new to PHP), but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Am I misusing the for loops here? Or should I suspect that something is wrong with the output I'm getting from R? (It will take the distance from the first point of `groupA`, and every point in `groupB`, add them to a dataframe, and repeat this until everything has been accounted for, and then filter the results of points that satisfy the cap).

Thanks for any guidance or advice on why I may be getting different outputs?

Comment: Curious, why translate from R to PHP? Both can command line call any script and pass args.

Comment: Lol I wish I could answer this to be honest. The main computer the sofrware has to run on doesn't have R installed, and they don't want to install it.

Comment: Hopefully they know R is open-source with possibly a lighter footprint than PHP. But please post some data, fuller code block so we can help. Right now code is not compilable and we do not know source data or desired results. Even R code can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by putting the results in two different arrays. But I took a pass at what it looks like you're trying to do.

```
// Two groups of points with each point consisting of [x,y]
$a = [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1], [10,1]];
$b = [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [10,0]];

$capLength = 1.9;

// Returns all points in a and b that are less than $capLength units of distance
function findPointsLessThanCapDistance($a, $b, $capLength)
{
    $results = [];
    // Loop through first group of points
    foreach ($a as $aIndex => $pointA) {
        // Loop through each point in second group per point in first group
        foreach ($b as $pointB) {
            // Check the distance between points
            if (distance($pointA, $pointB) <= $capLength) {
                // If there's a match, we need to put the results somewhere
                // This is what you'd change to put them into different arrays
                // or format them differently
                if (!array_key_exists($aIndex, $results)) {
                    $results[$aIndex] = [
                        'pointA' => $pointA,
                        'matches' => []
                    ];
                }
                $results[$aIndex]['matches'][] = $pointB;
                // End storing this matching point and move on to next pair
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

// Could be any other calculation
function distance($pointA, $pointB)
{
    return sqrt(($pointA[0] - $pointB[0]) ** 2 + ($pointA[1] - $pointB[1]) ** 2);
}

print_r(findPointsLessThanCapDistance($a, $b, $capLength));

// What results will be afterwards
$results = [
    [
        ['pointA'] => [0,1],
        ['matches'] => [[0,0], [1,0]]
    ],
    [
        ['pointA'] => [1,1],
        ['matches'] => [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]]
    ],
    etc.
];
```

Notice that this is O(n^2), so not the fastest for large sets of points. There are optimizations that could be done if we had more bounds on the data sets.